# How to take a full page screenshot of headless browser with python-selenium within an iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I am testing a non-public webpage and want to take a full-page screenshot of an iframe inside the page (when running automated tests within a python-selenium framework with firefox and chrome).

There are some solutions to take a full page screenshot (like [here](https://gist.github.com/fabtho/13e4a2e7cfbfde671b8fa81bbe9359fb)), but they do not deal with iframes.

I have two(!) iframes and I need to take the full-page screenshot from the innermost iframe.

How to do that?

Comment: do you try it with switch_to_frame and then screenshot??

Comment: Yes I tried exactly that, but the code takes only a screenshot from the 'visible' page. The window information the code gets seem to be from the top-level DOM element, and not from the iframe within.

Comment: so try to get second iframe visible, is it displayed at other window??